# Determing file exists (yes/no) in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My client just upgraded from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2016. One stored procedure used 15-20 times per day runs through a table of file names and reports for each on whether it exists.

Previously it used `xp_FileExist`, but it now seems to require admin rights to be used. I can't give all 176 users admin rights and keep my job.

I found articles suggesting use of `GRANT IMPERSONATE` and `EXECUTE AS USER` but can't get it to work.

```
-- Old code works only for administrators
-- non-administrators ALWAYS get 0 for result even when file exists

EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @docUNC, @FileExists OUTPUT

-- code run using admin account

SELECT SUSER_NAME() LOGIN_Name, USER_NAME() username;
```

Results

```
LOGIN_Name                   username
--------------------------------------
DomainName\potomcandice      dbo

-- attempted new code for grant impersonate (want to let maronj impersonate potomcandice)

GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER:: maronj TO potomcandice

-- New code

EXECUTE AS USER='potomcandice' 

EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @docUNC, @FileExists OUTPUT
```

Still get 0 for result even when the file does exist.

Hoping for suggestions on either
a) how to use "Grant Impersonate" and "Execute as User/Login" or
b) alternatives to xp_fileexist that do not involve xp_commandshell.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the service account has access to the folder in question? (It would probably throw an error but worth checking)

Comment: Yes.  Service account has rights.  When windows user has SQL admin rights then EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist returns accurate results.  Otherwise, returns 0 even when file exists.

Comment: That's an undocumented function that *shouldn't* be used except for administration scripts. The database has no business looking at the local file system.

Comment: `upgraded from SQL Server 2000` there were a *lot* of changes especially around security in those 16 years. SQL Server 2005 or 2008 *disabled* most sensitive features like `xp_cmd`. Those features aren't needed anyway - SQL Server Agent can execute external programs just fine. Any powershell script can work with files, and even Agent jobs can include Powershell steps.

Comment: What are you using `xp_fileexist` for? Whatever it is, there are better ways to do it

Comment: Users add document records to the database using the application (currently 25,000 documents with more added each day).  This generates a specific location where the document will be stored and a Scan coversheet for getting it there.  I need a way to report on which documents are where they are actually supposed to be and which are not.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos :  I get that you think this is a bad idea.  What I'm hoping for is suggestions instead of criticism.  I need a way for SQL to report on whether or not files listed in a table exist based on user specified criteria of what project they belong to, who created the record, what type of document, etc.

Comment: You can't get any suggestions if you don't explain what the *actual* problem is. As for reading data and checking for file existence, that's the job of external applications, not the database. You can easily write a Powershell script that does that. Unless you're talking about Full Text Search or [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) storage, in which case the files are owned by SQL Server

Comment: I agree - a better way to do this is run some powershell that connects to the database, finds the records it needs to check, checks them and writes back. You can run this regularly from SQL Agent. It depends how often files are uploaded, how quickly you need to know, and whether files get deleted afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I use `xp_fileexist` inside a function that I found [here](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30527/sql-server-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory/) and ran into the same problem where it didn't return correct results to non-admins.  The solution in my environment was to simply add `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` to the function definition as shown below.

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnFileExists(@Path VARCHAR(8000)) RETURNS BIT WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS 

/*  Returns 1 if a file exists at the suppied Path.  Returns 0 if it doesn't.  
    Uses WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER to enable use by non-admins.

    Source: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/30527/sql-server-how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-directory/
*/

BEGIN
     DECLARE @Result INT
     EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @Path, @Result OUTPUT
     RETURN @Result
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Find your SP in Object Explorer, go to SP Properties. In an opened window go to Permissions
Then click "Search" under the SP name.
hit "Browse" to find object name and mark "Public". Click OK.
Then Mark Grant "Execute" and try if it works.

This should do the trick

Comment: Already marked to give role "Public" execute permissions.  Users can execute stored procedure, but do not get accurate results.  EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'c:\test.txt' returns 0 (aka file not found)

Comment: I'd need to know details of the Stored Proc to give any further advice. Will be helpful to know what the SP does before fixing the issue.

Comment: Issue is not stored procedure.  Issue is with EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist only returning valid results when user is an admin.  All others get 0 indicating no match found even when file exists.

Comment: Modifying system stored procedure permissions without knowing what they do or what the implications are isn't wise. They are restricted for a *reason*. They are *not* needed for anything other than admin scripts and shouldn't be enabled unless one *fully* understands the consequences